# Hue effect for Image - iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just wonder, if there is any possibility to make an hue effect for Image, but not using OpenGl ES, preferably using CALayer.
I have spent some time looking for an answer, but still nothing.

tnx

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about tinting an image? A quick way (although probably not the best—for that you'll need a custom solution) would be to check out Quartz's blending options:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101

Comment: The Hue blend mode might be what you're looking for:

"To use this blend mode, call the function CGContextSetBlendMode with the constant kCGBlendModeHue."

Comment: Yes, this one I've found as well, but I need a solution like Apple done as an example "GLImageProcessing" where user can affect image hue by slider, but without Open GL Es. Maybe I am missing something, but this does not look like that.

Comment: Quoting from that page, "Specifies to use the luminance and saturation values of the background with the hue of the foreground image."

So have a UISlider which adjusts the value of UIColor (use an HSB color, not RGB). The slider adjusts the hue of the UIColor, and set that color as the foreground color. You could also have more sliders to adjust intensity of the hue (opacity of foreground in your code), as well as the saturation and brightness of the color if you want to give the user that much control. 

Short of going to OpenGL ES, I'd say that this is about as much as you're going to get.

Comment: This is a good answer, but having tried this in the past I can tell you that performance in 'real-time' (ie, with a slider) on iOS sucks. It's fine for triggering hue changes in response to a button press or preset, but when you want real-time feedback with a slider you'll be looking at a very low FPS/refresh rate (2-3FPS). If you need it to have half decent responsiveness in response to a variable slider I'm afraid it's probably OpenGL or nothing. We ended up reimplementing our image tint in OpenGL due to this.

Comment: I thought as much…but what device is that on? I'd think maybe the more modern devices (3GS onwards) might be able to handle it better, at least…

Comment: My observation around playing with CALayers and animation is that my old 3G iPhone can handle more then my iPod 4th gen. Not sure why, but seems to me that its not about RAM or CPU, but graphic chipset

Comment: The problem with kCGBlendModeHue is that produces a different effect of a simple hue change: It preserves the luminance and consequently alter the brightness. It is a different effect. The iPhone 4 might be slower in some cases because it needs to draw 4 times the number of pixels of the 3Gs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try copying the visible portion of the original image to an RGB bitmap, and writing Neon ASM to recalculate each pixel's RGB given some linear color space transform.  Something in the Accelerate DSP framework might also be suitable.  Then update the CALayer's contents with the modified bitmap image.  Might be fast enough for a decent frame rate for a reasonable sized portion of the image.  If the slider doesn't move for a bit, update the rest of the image as well.

Comment: This sounds, that can work, but I am afraid that the recalculation can makes serious performance problems.