# process brightness on specific part of image

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, image-processing, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am creating an application in which i am displaying image view with image and processing brightness on the image using slider. I want that brightness should be done only on the selected part of image and not on the entire image.

I want the brightness should be processed only on the central part of the image without using openGl Image processing.

Please help me to solve this problem. Hey guys Please help me its important for me.

Comment: Have you referred following - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219050/increase-decrease-brightness-of-a-uiimageview

Comment: i am trying it without using openGLImageProcessing please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Then you can refer following threads, there is enough discussion on this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880109/image-manipulation-using-slider-in-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346209/hue-effect-for-image-ios

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this. One is to overide the drawRect: UIView method and use a mask. Another is to draw the bitmap yourself in a CGContext. Yet another is with OpenGL.

What have you tried?

Comment: i am trying it without using openGLImageProcessing please help me to solve the problem